# ¿Como puedo poner un cero o null en una columna donde no hay correspondencia?

Tags: sql-server

Tengo la siguiente consulta, pero necesito que donde sigue la secuencia es decir el 1, en la otra tabla no "existen" valores por decirlo de una manera, hay forma de poner un cero o null en esa parte?
Ejemplo
ClaveVendedora    #ventas
0               1
1               0/null
2               12
3               14
Y así espero puedan ayudarme
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Edita tu pregunta y pon el codigo como texto

Comment: debes hacer left join para que te traiga el valor asi sea nullo